# This tag is [history]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The tag [history](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) (currently 80 questions, no tag wiki) is utterly useless. If a question is on-topic on this site, then it is about history, and if it not about history, then it is off-topic and needs to be removed. Having this tag here is equivalent to having a [programming] tag on Stack Overflow - it adds nothing useful to the post.

Can we move this tag to the dustbin of [history] or otherwise make it a footnote in the [history] of our site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I agree that the [history] tag is completely useless. As per [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239189/how-should-we-make-requests-to-block-tags), it might be possible to block the tag altogether, but first we should probably "burninate" it, which really just means removing it from every question where it occurs.

Edit: I have now burninated the tag, and added a remark in the tag info imploring users not to use this tag.

Comment: Re: "I have .... added a remark in the tag " Of course, now that the tag is gone, the tag-info no longer exists. (IIRC, the moderators have access to the orphaned tag-wikis. Regular users [can use SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/hsm/query/1231351/orphaned-tag-wikis). But the original tag name can only be guessed.)

Comment: In this particular case, the orphaned tag-wiki will only appear in SEDE after the next data update. The revision history can be seen here: [tag wiki](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/posts/12890/revisions) and [tag excerpt](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/posts/12891/revisions).