# Those who do not know [history] are doomed to recreate it

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Six months ago, the [history](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag was [burninated](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/349/6976) as useless.

The tag was supposedly [blacklisted](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/196/6976) as early as *2014*, but has come back repeatedly, including in [2020](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/332/6976).

The tag (at the time of posting of this question) has [15 questions](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) and still no tag wiki. It is completely useless, about as useful as a [programming] tag on Stack Overflow, a [vintage] tag on Retrocomputing SE, or a [language] tag on Linguistics SE.

I believe it is high time to burninate this tag for the last time and blacklist it.

Comment: I am removing the tag from the existing questions - would do it over a span of days so as to not bump all the questions at once. On a side note, I had started removing the tag from new questions since last year (after your post) - still seem to have missed some since the number of such questions increased.

Comment: Update: the [history] tag has now been successfully burninated, hopefully for the last time.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist the tag is [history].

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the problem is with the way the block was implemented (as site mods can verify on [this page](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/admin/blocklist), which lists all blocked tags and other blocked input for the site).

The regex for this particular tag-blocking seems to specifically check for a tag name consisting solely of `history-` followed by one or more "word characters" (i.e. alphanumeric characters or underscores).

So as written, something like `history-of` matches the regex (meaning [history-of](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) can't be created as a tag). But just `history` doesn't match the regex (since it doesn't have the hyphen or a word character after it), and neither does `history-of-science` (since it has at least one non-word character: the hyphen) – meaning it doesn't stop [history](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) or [history-of-science](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-science) from being (re)created as tags.

---

The tag block has now been fixed. A dev has updated the regex for the blocklist to ensure that `history` will be blocked (i.e. can no longer be created as a tag), as well as anything beginning with the word `history` followed by any combination of dashes and alpha-numeric chars.

The tag still needs to be manually removed from the questions it's on (which I believe can be done by moderators or other users). Once this tag is "burninated", users should no longer be able to recreate it.

Comment: Can you share the regex?